# Does anyone know how to find dead pixels on a phone screen automatically?

Tags: java, python, opencv, screen, pixel

does anyone know how a program can find dead pixels on a phone screen?

I found a lot of dead pixel finding tools and all of their implementations looks similar. It's showing a single-color screen, such as red, green, blue, white and black. Then, we need to check if there's any dots with different color (which is dead pixels) manually.

Is it possible to find the dead pixels automatically?

Comment: can you use a second device with a camera to capture that display?

Comment: Can you use the same device (the smartphone, presumably having a camera, ideally a front camera) by placing it in front of a mirror?

Comment: yes, actually the app that I want to create is using the second device to capture that display. but, the problem is, "is it possible to process the image and find the dead pixels automatically?"

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't.  Rendering the pixels is a "write-only" process, much like sending a message to the console.  There is no feedback from the physical pixels to indicate whether they turned on as expected.  Think of it like a TV screen: the broadcast studio has no way to tell whether you got the program.  They simply send out the signal; you pick it up or ignore it, depending on how you set your hardware state.

Comment: thanks for the insight! however, I found an app, they basically asked us to take a picture of our phone (front side). it can detect if there's a dead / stucked line pixel, and the screen is shaded.

how was that possible?

Comment: @JevonAverill "the basically asked us to take a picture" You take a picture and the app scans if it contains dead pixels. That is done on a seperate device, not on a device that contains the dead pixel. If you crack your screen at take a screenshot, that crack is not shown on the screenshot because the screenshot captures what the phone is supposed to display in that moment not what it actually displays. But if you take a image of the crack with a seperate phone of course you have a picture of that crack.

Comment: yes, that's correct. the scanning process is done on a separate device. but how to scan the dead pixels?

Comment: @JevonAverill Thats image processing basics. Take *any* book on image processing and it contains the information. You start with having the orioginal phone display a *reference image* that you know, then on the second device (which took the image) detect the edges of the phone and distortion, correct the distortion and then compare the un-distorted image to the *reference* image. You add a bit noise reduction and all anomalies that are left are dead pixels.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Polygnome, do you have reference for this implementation?

Comment: @JevonAverill As I said, every basic book on image processing deals with that (not literally with dead pixel recognition, but with recognition of anomalies wrt. a reference image).